# Kill foreground service when activity destroy

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

I use foreground service for playing music.
I've done research and figured out that process keep living even if I call stopForeground(true) and stopSelf(). It doesn't seem to work if I call it from the onDestroy of my activity. But if I call them from another place for example when user clicks button, it works.

But how to do that my service to be killed when app is killed.

[image]

[image]

```
private const val EMPTY_ROOT = "emptyRoot"
private val TAG = SoundsService::class.java.name

class SoundsService : MediaBrowserServiceCompat() {

@Inject
lateinit var mediaSession: MediaSessionCompat

@Inject
lateinit var callback: MediaSessionCallback

override fun onCreate() {
    inject()
    super.onCreate()

    mediaSession.apply {
        setCallback(callback)

        isActive = true
    }
    sessionToken = mediaSession.sessionToken
}

override fun onGetRoot(
    clientPackageName: String,
    clientUid: Int,
    rootHints: Bundle?
): BrowserRoot? {
    return BrowserRoot(EMPTY_ROOT, null)
}

override fun onLoadChildren(
    parentId: String,
    result: Result<MutableList<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>>
) {}

override fun onDestroy() {
    mediaSession.run {
        isActive = false
        release()
    }
    stopForeground(false)
    stopSelf()
    super.onDestroy()
}
}
```

Comment: Having all your `Activities` and `Services` destroyed, and ending the process, are two different things. Android generally terminates your app when it decides it doesn't want it around any more. If there's a possibility the user might return to the app, then Android is free to leave the process up. Try `System.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work in the `onDestroy`. Just make sure your are calling it, before `super` call. And use `ApplicationContenxt` for that as well.

```
    applicationContext.startForegroundService(Intent(this, ServiceTest::class.java));
    applicationContext.stopService(Intent(this, ServiceTest::class.java))
```

Comment: I use the same code but it doesn't work. Check screens. Process keep living.

Comment: @Subuday And use application context, asI described above. `MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().stopForegroundServices`

Comment: Doesn't help, process's still alive

Comment: @GensaGames I don't get it. If you're in `onDestroy()`, clearly your service is stopping. What is the point of even trying to call `stopSelf()`?

Comment: Take Application Context. From context.

Answer (score -2):

Have you checkt for any crashes when you call stopForeground(true) or stopSelf()

Comment: App just keep living

Comment: have you tried context.stopService(Intent(context, serviceClass)) ?

Comment: Yes, check screens.

Comment: I think you confuse your app and service. For what i know is that android studio will show if your app is alive on your phone. This is shown with com.example.sleepysounds .  However your service is stopped your app is still running somewhere in the background. If u kill ur app this will be com.example.sleepysounds (dead)

Comment: If I remove my app from "Recently used apps" without starting foregrounds service, just background service I get my process [DEAD]. If I use foreground service, process keep life. But I expect it's to [DEAD]

Comment: then i dont' know. What i defined above should work. It works for my apps.